# Subnet Issue - Multiple instances match the same subnet

Tags: networking, network-interface

I have my */etc/network/interfaces* file configured as the following

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.100
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1

allow-hotplug wlan0

iface wlan0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.200
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1

wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface default inet dhcp

iface wlan1 inet static
        address 192.168.42.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I am receving an error which states that **eth0 wlan0** are **Multiple instances match the same subnet.**

How is this the case? Are default settings implicitly being applied which I should manually create an entry for?

I have tried changing the **address** entry within wlan0 to the following

```
iface wlan0 inet static
        address 192.169.42.1
```

and also to

```
iface wlan0 inet static
        address 194.169.42.1
```

However the error remains exactly the same that **eth0 wlan0** - **Multiple instances match the same subnet**

Comment: @buntybudia is this your question? In which case, please edit it with your JamesParker44 account, or use the [contact us](http://unix.stackexchange.com/contact) link to request an account merge.

Comment: Did you try removing the gateway from one of the interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

you should not use same IP subnet 192.168.1.0/24 for multiple network interface.

If you want to leave your interface wlan0 in 192.168.1.0/24 subnet, Change eth0 static IP and DHCP server to a different subnet 192.168.10.0/24 for example.